# "stop if true" flag on conditional formatting - apache poi

Tags: formatting, apache-poi, conditional-statements

is there any way to set the "stop if true" flag on conditional formatting rules with apache poi ?

I didnt find anything about that.

Comment: Not in general, as far as I know. With `XSSF` (*.xlsx) it is possible using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCfRule`, http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTCfRule.java#CTCfRule.setStopIfTrue%28boolean%29.

Comment: thank you, that was not exactly what i was looking for, but it worked